# Exporting SSRS report to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am COMPLETELY new to SSRS and was thrown into the fire with this so PLEASE be patient. :D

I belieive I am certain that whatever format is used in the report is the format it will appear in when you download it to Excel (merged cells, auto wrap text, etc..). However, I have VERY A-Type Project Managers who seem to think that you can "pre-set" the formatting elsewhere (i.e. the queries) to ensure that the formatting stays consistent when exporting.

Is there somewher I can refer to that shows what can/can't be done with formatting prior to exporting into Excel so that I can go to them and definitively show them that what you see is what you get when you export?

Thank you for your patience in answering this.

Sincerely,

A Smith

Comment: You have no control from SSRS as to the formatting (merged cells, etc) when exporting to Excel.  SSRS does it auto-magically. I'm sorry that I don't have an article to point to.  With that said, if you simplify your report so that it's just a table (no header / footer or images).  You'll get what your PM requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links related to Export to Excel from SSRS. Sorry, I am not sure if that is what you are exactly looking for.

[**Merge Ahead**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbal/archive/2006/07/08/659545.aspx) *(blogs.msdn.com)*

[**Ensure best Excel export formating from SQL Server Reporting Services**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2007/06/28/ensure-best-excel-export-formating-from-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx) *(blogs.msdn.com)*

Comment: Thank you. I figured as much but being so new to this I wanted to put it out there and get some more expert opinions. Thank you everyone who responded :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's another useful link: [How to eliminate merged and hidden Cells issue from Excel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how_to_eliminate_merged_and_hidden_cells_issue_from_excel_export_of_ssrs_report/archive/2013/05/17/how-to-eliminate-merged-and-hidden-cells-issue-from-excel-export-of-a-ssrs-report.aspx)

/Jakob